# Weird error in Visual Studio 2010 after installing extensions

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Today after installing extensions (e.g. Power tools) to my Visual Studio 2010 I have encountered this error while launching it ( specifically when I start editing a file from solution )

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
Visual Studio has encountered an exception. This may be caused by an extension.

You can get more information by running the application together with the /log parameter on the command line, and then examining the file 'C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\ActivityLog.xml'.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

I have tried uninstalling all of the extesnions but I still get the same error.

So I launched VS with `/log` and then I have these 2 errors in the log

`System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop.IVsTextReplaceEvents'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{CF9928D9-65AE-4319-A446-94ED5C45ECDE}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)). at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.GetCOMIPFromRCW(Object objSrc, IntPtr pCPCMD, Boolean& pfNeedsRelease) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop.IVsTextReplaceEvents.OnReplace(ChangeInput[] pCI) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.VsTextBufferAdapter.OnTextBufferChangedHighPriority(Object sender, TextContentChangedEventArgs e) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Utilities.GuardedOperations.RaiseEvent[TArgs](Object sender, EventHandler 1 eventHandlers, TArgs args)`

`System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.IVsTextStreamEvents_Private'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{96FC7D44-BCDD-4F00-AE4D-07E26B2C0E52}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)). at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.GetCOMIPFromRCW(Object objSrc, IntPtr pCPCMD, Boolean& pfNeedsRelease) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.IVsTextStreamEvents_Private.OnChangeStreamText(Int32 iPos, Int32 iOldLen, Int32 iNewLen, Int32 fLast) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.VsTextBufferAdapter.OnTextBufferChanged(Object sender, TextContentChangedEventArgs e) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Utilities.GuardedOperations.RaiseEvent[TArgs](Object sender, EventHandler 1 eventHandlers, TArgs args)`

Anyone knows what is this  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be the problem described here (including a registry fix):
[visual Studio crashes constantly](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/546369/)